# Extracting All Unique Patterns in Column of Strings (Python, Pandas DF)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a project for work in manufacturing in which all parts for each ordered item has a unique 6-digit code; there are 68000 records. All of the part codes are put into a single column, into a single string, as such with each parent string having different lengths:

[Screenshot of column output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vulVK.png)

I would like to know if there is an easier way to separate these strings, turn each unique code into a column and then encode the column 1 if present and 0 if absent from the parent string.

```
AAX04X  ABXN6X  A5DB1X...
  1        1       1
  1        0       1
  0        1       0
        ...
```

Here is what I have so far, but it takes a long time to run:

```
line = df.column[0]
split = [line[i:i+6] for i in range(0,len(line),6)]

for r in range(0,len(df.column)):
    new_line = df.column[r]
    new_split = [new_line[i:i+6] for i in range(0,len(new_line),6)]

    for code in new_split:
        if code not in split:
            split.append(code)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the strings into 6-character chunks with `wrap` and `split`, then `get_dummies` for one-hot encoding:

```
# generate some test data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    's': [''.join(x) for x in np.random.choice(list('AB'), (100, 24))]
})

# split into 6-character chunks and one-hot encode them
df['s'].str.wrap(6).str.get_dummies('\n')
```

Output:

```
    AAAAAA  AAAAAB  AAAABA  AAAABB  AAABAA  AAABAB  AAABBA  AAABBB  AABAAA  \
0        0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0   
1        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
2        0       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0   
3        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1   
4        0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0   
..     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...   
95       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0   
96       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0   
97       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
98       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0   
99       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: Thank you! I am running your suggestion now; however, with there being 68000 records it is taking quite a while to run. I will update once it completes

Comment: @AnttonHammarskjold Interesting. How long are these strings? I've tested on 100k strings with 24 characters each, and it runs in about 30 seconds on my laptop

Comment: It worked well, thank you. Each of the strings are 4500-5000 characters.